# Searching in Mac Mail: I want the e-mail, not the thread

Tags: macos, email, apple-mail

In Mail, when I search the mail archives for a string, Mail brings up all the mail threads that have e-mails in them that, in turn, have that string.  Well, that's better than nothing, but most of the time all I want are the isolated e-mails that have the string.  I do not want the whole thread.  When I get the threads, I still have more searching to do.  Is there some way to convince Mail to give me the isolated e-mails, not the threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not possible. But after searching for mail with in a mailbox with option+cmd+f you can select a mail which will open the thread. Mail will scroll down to the first mail in which it finds the string. Doing cmd+f then opens up a search bar for the mails within that thread and Mail.app already fills out the string you were looking for in the mailbox.